# How to turn these two methods into a delegate call?

Tags: c#, delegates

I know that the following can be done with a delagate. What I don't know is how to do it.
I have very little experience using delegates. I refactored out the specific stuff to each method and
left the shared information in them.

```
public void AddCustomer(UserReportSavePermissionRequest permissionRequest)
{
    var key = AddGroupName(permissionRequest.GroupName);
    var reportKey = AddCustomerSpecific(permissionRequest, key);
    AddPermission(permissionRequest, reportKey);
}

public void AddOnline(UserReportSavePermissionRequest permissionRequest)
{
    var key = AddGroupName(permissionRequest.GroupName);
    var reportKey = AddOnlineSpecific(permissionRequest, key);
    AddPermission(permissionRequest, reportKey);
}
```

I am not sure how to make this happen. Also I am looking for a good tutorial on delegates to help me get
a better understanding of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `AssociateCustomerReportsToGroupNameBy` and `AssociateOnlineReportsToGroupNameBy` have identical signatures, you could eliminate the repetition of the common code by passing in a delegate that has the same signature as these two methods, and calling it from the implementation. Rather than defining new delegates, you could use `Func<UserReportSavePermissionRequest,string,R>` and `Action<T> types for it. Type`R`corresponds to the type of`reportKey`. I am assuming that`key`is of type`string`, and that`ReportGroupNameKeys`returns`string[]`.

```
public void AddItem(
    UserReportSavePermissionRequest permissionRequest
,   Func<UserReportSavePermissionRequest,string,T> getReportKey
) {
    var key = AddGroupName(permissionRequest.GroupName);
    var reportKey = getReportKey(permissionRequest, key);
    AddPermission(permissionRequest, reportKey);
}
```

The caller needs to pass two additional parameters now. The call of `AddItem` that corresponds to your `AddCustomer` would look like this:

```
AddItem(permissionRequest, AddCustomerSpecific);
```

The call of `AddOnline` would be

```
AddItem(permissionRequest, AddOnlineSpecific);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't give much explanation as to why you want these to be delegates so I will assume you want to be able to call these methods from other classes.

Create a delegate type that matches the signature of your method(s):

Your signature for your delegates is one with no return value and 1 parameter of type `UserReportSavePermissionRequest`.  So add this delegate as a public delegate or in a separate .cs file in Visual Studio

```
public delegate void UserReportSavePermissionRequestDelegate(UserReportSavePermissionRequest);
```

Now lets use it to call one of your 2 methods that implement this signature:

```
//some code where you want to pass in a delegate so the delegated method can be called:
someObject.Register( this.AddCustomer);  // <-- you are passing a method that matches the delegate signature
```

The `someObject.Register()` method would be defined like this:

```
public void Register(UserReportSavePermissionRequestDelegate del)
{
   ... //do some stuff
   var someVar  = CreateRequest(); // <-- this needs to be the UserReportSavePermissionRequest type
   del(someVar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a delegate as class level variable

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(UserReportSavePermissionRequest)
```

Instantiate the delegate

```
MyDelegate del = new MyDelegate(AddCustomer);
MyDelegate del2 = new MyDelegate(AddOnline);
```

Alternatively, if you can even chain the delegates.

invoke the method on the delegate by passing a UserReportSavePermissionRequest instance

```
del(permissionRequest);
```

.Net provides in built delegates. They are Func, Action and Predicate
A Func delegate represents a method that takes parameters and returns something 
An Action delegate represents a method that takes parameters and returns nothing
A predicate returns a bool

Note that the parameters to the methods are optional and not always required
In you case, the Action delegate can be used if wish to pass the methods as parameter to a method

e.g

```
public void MyMethod(Action<UserReportSavePermissionRequest> act, UserReportSavePermissionRequest obj)
{
    act.Invoke(obj);
}
```

The above method can be called as

```
UserReportSavePermissionRequest obj;

MyMethod(AddCustomer, obj);
MyMethod(AddOnline, obj)
```